# angularjs internet explorer css issue

Tags: css, angularjs, internet-explorer

The following code works in google crome but does not work in Internet Explorer(9 to 11). value of {{value}} does not executed.

```
$scope.dictionary = { 'Item': 25, 'Name': 25, 'order': 12.5, 'value': 37.5 };
 var stemp = '<div ng-repeat="(name, value) in dictionary">' +
            '<div class="templateHeader" style=\"width:{{value}}px;\">{{name}} </div></div>';
```

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? I guess it's about css. Try to open string with double quotes `"` and inside string use only single quote `'`

Comment: Why would you store HTML inside the variable? gone are those days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wow, may be i found the answer. here is revised code

```
var stemp = '<div ng-repeat="(name, value) in dictionary">' +
            '<div class="templateHeader" ng-style="{ width: value +\'px\' }">{{name}} </div></div>';
```